# GCC Profiler, time unaccounted for

Tags: c, gcc, profiler, gprof

I am currently using the min-gw GCC profiler tool `gprof` to find the slow portions of my code. I compile the code with

```
gcc -p -pg -o3 example.c -o example.exe
```

After running the file I use

```
 gprof example.exe > data.txt
```

My program prints its running time to be ~8 seconds, but the data.txt only shows the functions of my program, which account for 3.47 seconds. I imagine that unaccounted for time is used in other C functions, such as `malloc`, `free`, etc, but I still need to know where the time is being used. Any thoughts?

Comment: Any chance you are confusing execution time and wall-clock time? How does your program come to the conclusion it takes 8 seconds? How much I/O does your program do? Is it CPU bound, memory bound, or I/O bound?

Comment: I am using time.h, time_t start = time(0), time_t end= time(0),, total time = difftime(end,start)

Answer (score 1):

gprof together with most other profilers sample, rather than present accurate results so it's completely possible that you're getting less time than the actual execution time. Further gprof, according to [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2010-02/msg00255.html) only cares about the code inside the program, not any other library functions that are called so this is also a factor.

Try using valgrind with the callgrind tool for a performance analysis. It's quite good and intuitive and you can visualize it with multiple other tools.

Another thing you can use is [gperftool](https://code.google.com/p/gperftools/) which can attach to a process and show you where most of the time is spent (in percentage).

There are really good proprietary profilers such as [Intel vTune](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-vtune-amplifier-xe) but in my experience there hasn't been a time where I couldn't find what I needed using gperftools.

Answer (score 1):

There's a very good proprietary profiler - you own it.

It's any debugger that can be paused or interrupted, even GDB, augmented with the best artificial intelligence you can get - your head.

Some people call it [*"poor man's profiler"*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771), but it works, and it can find anything a profiler can find
(*especially* gprof) and plenty that it can't.

If you want, I'll explain why.